# How can I play MIDI files in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, midi

I'm using python 2.7. I can use pygame to play a midi file in IDLE, but when I use the exact same code in pycharm, no sound is played. I know pygame is being initialised correctly, as it prints the output `(6, 0)`.